# Detecting whether banner ads pass link juice

Tags: seo, advertising, links, backlinks, banners

I wanted to determine the relative SEO value of the advertising links passed by this website: http://www.garden.org/.

On the right side you'll notice several advertising banners that, when clicked, redirect you to the appropriate website. If you inspect any of these banners you'll notice that while the `a href` has a bunch of the usual ad garbage in the URL, there's nothing in there that's `nofollow`.

Why is it that when I check out any of these site's backlink profiles (via OpenSiteExplorer) that I can't find any trace of backlinks from `garden.org`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi NotMuchOfAProgrammer,

It's not a real backlink since the JavaScript is injecting the URL after the page has been loaded. If you disable JavaScript you will see:

```
<noscript>
    <a href="http://ads.garden.org/www/delivery/ck.php?n=aa4a0d78&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://ads.garden.org/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=104&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=aa4a0d78" border="0" alt="">
    </a>
</noscript>
```

Which has no backlink ;).

Most sites that you buy space for advertising will use a JavaScript, Redirect, Flash Ad or a simple `nofollow`. Good sites do this because selling of links is against Google's policy and they actually downrank their in rankings and PageRank if they are caught doing so.

Comment: Hi bybe, I didn't know that. You learn something new every day in this business. :) Thank you, you've answered my question perfectly.

Comment: No problem at, glad I could help ;)

Comment: I'd upvote your answer if I had enough reputation to do so. :)